# Which of the two is recommended way of passing variable php?

Tags: php

I want to pass a variable from one page to another. It may carry some sensitive data so focus remains on security. I have come through two ways

HTML-form:

```
<form action="target.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="key" value="foo" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
  'method'  => 'POST',
  'header'  => "Content-type: text/html\r\n",
  'content' => http_build_query(array('key' => 'foo'))
),
));
$return = file_get_contents('target.php', false, $context);
```

Which is more safer of the two? Any other method welcomed.

Comment: Session is the most secure method you have available.

Comment: Our suggestions could be more useful if you would expand a bit further on what exactly "pass a variable from one page to another" means, and where its value actually comes from.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov I want to pass post id's as such `<a href="post.php?postId=<?php echo $postid ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>` and some similar functions, was using simple url method but now want to swtich to more secure method.

Answer (score 0):

Most secure way to temporary store any value for future use in PHP is session. Session is super global variable of php and available at everywhere.

You can store all datatype values in session like integer, float, boolean or array as well.

After submitting your form, do process it and store expected values in session. Then use it on another page. After use unset its value. Below is the example how you can set session.

```
<?php

$_SESSION['myValue'] = 'your value to store'; //assign value to session.

echo $_SESSION['myValue']; // print value of session. If it store array then use print_r() to see values.

unset($_SESSION['myValue']); // unset session value

?>
```